# Is $SAFE = 4 and a timed execution limit enough to prevent eval's security vulnerabilities in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, security, eval

Here is my current implementation of a safe `eval` in Ruby:

```
$mthread = Thread.new {}
class SafeEval
  def self.safeEval code
    $killed = false
    $mthread = Thread.new {
      $SAFE = 4
      result = begin
        eval code
      rescue Exception => e
        "Error in eval: #{e}"
      end
      Thread.current[:evalResult] = result
    }
    Thread.new {
      sleep 3
      if $mthread.alive?
        $killed = true
        Thread.kill $mthread
      end
    }.join
    $mthread.join
    $killed ? 'Error in eval: Maximum execution time reached' : String($mthread[:evalResult])
  end
end
```

It uses `$SAFE = 4`. From my understanding, and from [this post I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2157272/3265998), that's not enough to stop security vulnerabilities. **However**, if I set a maximum execution time, and kill the thread running the code after the time expires, is that enough for a safe `eval`?

If not, why isn't it safe? Are there still any vulnerabilites? Is there any way to prevent these vulnerabilities as well?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Of course setting an execution time is not secure.  All you're doing then is making the execution path of whatever is executed *less predictable*.</strike>

Security is not about saying 'Oh, no untrusted code can cause trouble if it runs for less than 4s'.  Security starts with not letting untrusted code execute anywhere outside of a strict sandboxed environment.

Why are you using eval here?  What are you trying to accomplish?

edit- I'm an idiot, ignore, I read that as a timeout, not as a level. :P  That said, this works perfectly well on my local machine:

```
$mthread = Thread.new {}

class SafeEval
  def self.safeEval code
    $killed = false
    $mthread = Thread.new {
      $SAFE = 4
      result = begin
        eval code
      rescue Exception => e
        "Error in eval: #{e}"
      end
      Thread.current[:evalResult] = result
    }
    Thread.new {
      sleep 3
      if $mthread.alive?
        $killed = true
        Thread.kill $mthread
      end
    }.join
    $mthread.join
    $killed ? 'Error in eval: Maximum execution time reached' : String($mthread[:evalResult])
  end
end

SafeEval.safeEval("`cat /etc/passwd > /Users/usr/development/source/tests/test.txt`")
```

run that code on a web server that has a mail client or other method of connecting to remote servers, and an attacker can establish the user accounts on your machine and from there engage in social engineering to recover passwords.

Sandboxing is important because it prevents stuff like the above.  $SAFE is not enough in and of itself, and this is one of the reasons you never put something like eval() or anything else whose core job is to execute *untrusted code* in an environment that could be reached by an attacker.

Comment: Do you know what setting `$SAFE` does? He's not saying "no untrusted code can cause trouble if it runs for less than 4s"

Comment: Can you show a vulnerability that this is susceptible to?

Comment: @JanDvorak see the classic 'cat /etc/passwd' above.

Comment: Better now :-) can you suggest a solution that _is_ a sufficient sandbox?

Comment: The only solution is to not use eval.  If you need to execute 'commands' from untrusted hosts, define a fixed list of commands on a white list and permit only specific arguments in a way where injection or deserialization attacks cannot affect the server.  Having an eval in code that is reachable by the outside world is asking for trouble. Perhaps the easiest way to guard your system is to run this code inside a virtual machine (a la Vagrant) that has just got system accounts, firewalled from the rest of your network, and rebuildable in the event it gets owned.

Comment: The `cat` thing doesn't work because `\`` isn't allowed in safe level 4. Please provide a better example...

Answer (score 0):

If you consider 'being able to kill the bot' as security vulnerability, then $SAFE = 4 is not safe enough, as we found out while testing it.

People can execute this, without getting the 'unsafe eval' error:

```
loop { Thread.start { loop{} } }
```

This starts many threads within 3 seconds, and after enough executions this will have created lots and lots of threads, which has killed the bot while testing.

Or this:

```
Thread.start { loop { Thread.start { loop {} } } }
```

It starts a thread which keeps generating other threads. The timeout does not stop this.